# Find largest pair sum in array of integers

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, performance

How can I find the largest pair sum in an array of positive integers of size n, but with the integers at least at a distance k? (For example, if the first element is a[i], then the second element should be a[i+k] (or more).)

I tried this:

```
int max_sum = 0;
int sum;
for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
    for( int j = i + k; j < n; j++) {
        sum = arr_sums[i] + arr_sums[j];
        if ( sum > max_sum ) {
            max_sum = sum;

        }
    }
}
```

but it's too slow for large arrays.

Comment: Is the array sorted?

Comment: `int max_sum;` --> `int max_sum = INT_MIN;` because you use an *uninitialised variable*.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oops, my mistake, it's 0.

Comment: @Mitsos101 Edge case alert! The largest sum of two numbers, in a set of numbers, _could_ be negative.

Comment: @Oka My fault again, the integers are always positive.

Comment: Then why are they not `unsigned`?

Answer (score 10):

It's quite simple to do in O (n), not O (n²) like your solution.

```
For each j, 0 ≤ j < n, 
calculate m [j] = "largest element from a [j] to a [n - 1]. ". 
Obviously m [n - 1] = a [n - 1], m [j] = max (a [j], m [j + 1]). 

Then for each i, 0 ≤ i < n - k, calculate a [i] + m [i + k], 
and pick the largest of these.
```

It should be obvious how to do this without actually storing the values `m [j]` except for one.

Answer (score 4):

```
//assuming we checked first for n<=k
int max_lagged = arr_sums[0];
int max_sum = max_lagged+arr_sums[k];
int sum;
for (int i = k+1 ; i < n; i++) {
    if (arr_sums[i-k] > max_lagged) {
        max_lagged=arr_sums[i-k];
    }
    sum = arr_sums[i] + max_lagged;
    if ( sum > max_sum ) {
        max_sum = sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be n>=k?